# Exclude duplicates from an array in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, duplicates

I've been looking for a function or method in Google Apps Script that removes all the duplicates from an array (discarding the duplicates themselves) and keep only the unique values. For instance:

const chars = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'D'];

Expected result/output:

['C', 'D']

So far, I haven't been able to achieve that. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function removeDuplicates(a=['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'D']) {
  let oA = {pA:[]};
  //count the occurrence of each element
  a.forEach(e=>{ 
    if(!oA.hasOwnProperty(e)) {
      oA[e]=1;
      oA.pA.push(e);
    } else {
      oA[e]+=1;
    }
  });
  //return only the elements that only occur once
  Logger.log(oA.pA.filter(e => oA[e]==1));
}
```

This just counts the occurrences of each element and only returns the elements that only occur once.

Comment: That's it! Very concise and accurate. Thanks.